Application of Nash's Embedding Theorem for Constructing Pseudo-Riemannian Metrics
As you know, it is possible to define a Riemannian metric on a $\sigma$-compact manifold.
The proof using Nash's Whitney embedding theorem proceeds as follows:
Let $M$ be a $\sigma$-compact manifold.
Then there exists an embedding $\varphi : M \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ into a sufficiently high-dimensional Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^n$.
By pulling back the natural Riemannian metric $g_0$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$ via $\varphi$, we obtain a tensor field $g=\varphi^*g_0$ on $M$. Since $g_0$ is a symmetric tensor field, $g$ is also a symmetric tensor field.
Furthermore, at each point $p$ of $M$, $(d\varphi)_p$ is an injective linear map, so for any $X \in T_p(M)$ with $X \neq 0$, we have $(d\varphi)_p(X) \neq 0$.
Moreover, $g_0$ is positive-definite.
Therefore, $g$ is also positive-definite.
Would the theorem still hold if we replace "Riemannian metric" with "pseudo-Riemannian metric"?
For instance, we could define a pseudo-Riemannian metric $g_0$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$ by setting
$$ g_0(X, Y) = -(x_1 y_1) + (x_2 y_2) + \cdots + (x_m y_m), $$
where $X = (x_1, x_2, \dots, x_m)$ and $Y = (y_1, y_2, \dots, y_m)$.

Note that by the Poincare-Hopf index theorem and the existence of time-orientable double covers, a closed manifold which admits a Lorentzian metric has Euler characteristic zero. So however it could be applied to a genus $2$ closed surface, the construction must result in a metric with varying signature if it’s Lorentzian anywhere. Also, you can pull back an arbitrary metric using the map the Nash embedding theorem finds, but maybe you have something else in mind.

You seem to confuse Nash Embedding Theorem (isometric embeddings of Riemannian manifolds) and Whitney Embedding Theorem (smooth embeddings of smooth manifolds).

You are absolutely right. I meant to refer to Whitney embedding theorem but mistakenly wrote Nash's embedding theorem. I have corrected it now. Thank you very much!

Indeed, if $g_0$ is positive definite, then $g$ is also be positive definite.
However, if $g_0$ is non-degenerate, $g$ is not necessarily non-degenerate.
Assume that $g_0$ is non-degenerate.
To show that $g$ is non-degenerate, it is sufficient to demonstrate that for each point $p$ on $M$,
$$X \in T_p(M), X \neq 0 \rightarrow \exists Y \in T_p(M), g_p(X,Y) \neq 0.$$
Since $(d\varphi)_p$ is an injective and linear map, we have $X \neq 0 \rightarrow (d\varphi)_p(X) \neq 0$.
Furthermore, since $g_0$ is non-degenerate, there exists some $Z \in T_p(\mathbb{R})$ such that
$${g_0}_p((d\varphi)_p(X),Z) \neq 0.$$
If there exists $Y \in T_p(M)$ for this $Z$ such that $(d\varphi)_p(Y) = Z$, then ${g_0}_p((d\varphi)_p(X), Z) = g_p(X,Y) \neq 0.$
Therefore, we can conclude that $g_p$ is also non-degenerate. However, since $(d\varphi)_p$ is not surjective, such $Y$ does not necessarily exist.
